# TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe"

Tags: c++, node.js, npm-install, node-gyp

I feel like I've tried everything.

- I have installed and uninstalled every single version of Visual
  studio (from 2010 - 2017)
- I have attempted to install the build tools used for windows c++
- I have uninstalled node.js and reinstalled.

BUT NO matter what I do I still get the error:

```
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe".
```

I have attempted every "solution" i could find on `google` that discusses or descripe this issue.

When i run `npm install`

I get the following error:

```
    TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". file not found


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\src\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
learningbank@1.0.0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\src
`-- (empty)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this issue?

My operation system is "Windows 10 pro".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CL.exe is the command line build of VS. Couple of things I would look at:

1. When you install VS is the CL install optional, if so is it on?
2. Environment variables. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kezkeayy.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that "Platform Toolset", under project Properties > General settings, is set to the correct Visual Studio version you are using.

In my case, had downloaded a project from GitHub that was set to Visual Studio 2015 and I'm using VS 2017. After changing it worked.

You may want to confirm other settings under properties as well, as "Windows SDK Version", and make sure it's installed. You can check your Visual Studio installation under "Apps & Features" and modify.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install Visual Studio 2015. Still, I see this error. Later on I found that I must choose Custom Install, Select Visual C++ during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had a comparable problem building a new 'Hello World' console application. I took a look in the property pages (View - Other Windows - Property Manager) at Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user​. At Common Properties - VC++ Directories - Executable Directories it turned out that 'Inherit from parent or project defaults' was not checked. After checking that cl.exe was found.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved when I used visual studio 2015 instead of 2019 and also changed the windows SDK version from 10.0 to 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are a number of different causes/solutions to this problem.

I struggled for a bit and this worked for me (Windows 11/Visual Studio 22) :

- First confirm that cl.exe is present by typing cl.exe in the 'Developer PowerShell for VS 2022'
- If it recognized, go to Tools --> Command Line --> Developer Command Prompt
- Type where cl in the command line.
- Navigate to Advanced System Settings in Windows, select Environment Variables
- Edit the Path variable to include the location of cl.exe displayed from the 'where cl' command.