# TRK0005 Fails to loacte : "CL.exe"

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

In my Visual Studio 2019, I got this error.
In my solution file, I have two projects **Cuitest** and **Bodymake**r,
Bodymaker depends on Cuitest. I got this error in the bodymaker project.
[Please check the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFLb7.jpg)

Configproperties-> General-> character set-> Use multi Byte not working.

Comment: One odd thing: The question says Bodymaker but the error message says BodyMarkers. Is that supposed to be the same project?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436035/tracker-error-trk0005-failed-to-locate-cl-exe